# Failed to create table in tdengine

Tags: tdengine

I used tdengine to create table,but I have failed. My create sql is:

```
create table test (ts timestamp,key nchar(10),val int);
```

But I was failed becasue of these error:

> DB error: invalid operation: invalid column name (0.000760s)

I don’t know why this error occurred. Does someone one why ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because that column "key" is a keyword in TDengine. So you can't create a table witch column named "key". Further more, any of the key word should not be avoid in sql.
[TDengine's key word](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/administrator)

reference the [TDengine Parameter Limits and Reserved Keywords] chapter.